# Usage of comma joining adjectives and meaning of "low, broad forehead"

Tags: phrase-meaning, adjectives, commas

> At different times in history , writers and artists have admired pure , high foreheads or low , broad ones .

In this sentence , how many kinds of foreheads are there ?  2 or 4 ? I really confused the word ''  low , broad ones '' .

Comment: Punctuation point: no space before commas, full stops or question marks.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will ask more questions. _When you use punctuation, do it like this!_ ....... _When you use punctuation , don't do it like this !_

Comment: [Here](https://englishtips.quora.com/Spacing-Around-Punctuation-Marks) are some rules on spacing.

Answer (score 1):

> [Coordinate Adjectives](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000072.htm)
>   If two adjectives modify a noun in the same way, place a comma between the two adjectives. These are called coordinate adjectives.

So, there are have been **two** kinds of foreheads that have been admired in the past:

1. Foreheads that were pure *and* high ("pure, high foreheads")
2. Foreheads that were low *and* broad ("low, broad foreheads")

I'm not entirely sure what "low and broad" means, but I have a feeling this is an example.
[image]

> Fergie has one of the smallest foreheads in Hollywood, and is usually seen wearing loose, long waves with a centre hair part. This hairstyle is actually much better for her forehead, because it has a side hair part and added height at the front. ([Source.](http://www.thehairstyler.com/blogs/hairstyles/hairstyles-for-small-foreheads))